# Размер текста для setMessage в AlertDialog

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog

Как указать размер текста для `setMessage` в AlertDialog не используя стили, желательно через dimen прямо в коде.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        with(builder)
        {
            setMessage(R.string.overwrite)
            setTitle(R.string.title)
            setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            setPositiveButton(
                resources.getText(R.string.yes_mes),
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = positiveButtonClick)
            )
            setNegativeButton(
                resources.getText(R.string.no_mes),
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = negativetiveButtonClick)
            )
            show()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько костыльное решение через поиск TextView по id:

```
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    var dialog: AlertDialog? = null
    with(builder)
    {
        setMessage(R.string.overwrite)
        setTitle(R.string.title)
        setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        setPositiveButton(
            resources.getText(R.string.yes_mes),
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = positiveButtonClick)
        )
        setNegativeButton(
            resources.getText(R.string.no_mes),
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = negativetiveButtonClick)
        )
        dialog = show()
     }
     val textView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message) as? TextView;
     textView?.setTextSize(40);
```

Обратите внимание, что изменение размера текста должно происходить строго после того, как был вызван метод `show`!

Answer (score 1):

[Alex_Skvortsov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/365775/alex-skvortsov), спасибо! Я несколько исправил и скорректировал ваш код, что бы TextSize брался из `dimen`

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
var dialog: AlertDialog? // = nul 
with(builder)
{
    setMessage(R.string.overwrite)
    setTitle(R.string.title)
    setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    setPositiveButton(
        resources.getText(R.string.yes_mes),
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = positiveButtonClick)
    )
    setNegativeButton(
        resources.getText(R.string.no_mes),
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = negativetiveButtonClick)
    )
    dialog = show()
}
val textView = dialog?.findViewById(android.R.id.message) as? TextView
textView?.setTextSize(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.alertText_size)
)
```